# Did Iqbal offer funeral prayers for the killer of someone who wrote a blasphemous book?

Tags: india, british-empire, pakistan, south-asia

In 1929, Ilmuddin killed a man called Rajpal for writing a blasphemous book against Muhammad. He was later hanged by the British government.

According to several sources (like [here](https://www.rferl.org/a/the_deep_roots_of_pakistans_extremism/2270457.html)), the national poet of Pakistan, Iqbal, himself [placed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilm-ud-din#Funeral) Ilmuddin’s body in the grave and gave a short eulogy.

I cannot find any reliable source to authenticate this claim. What was the eulogy, and did Jinnah also attend the funeral?

Edit:  I'm looking for sources written by academics and professional historians. Even popular columns written by historians would do